# Change Progress Bar format to show x.x% in pyQt4

Tags: format, progress-bar, pyqt4

I have been trying to find out which the right syntax for the .setFormat() method of the ProgressBar is, but i cannot find any information about that. %p% just shows the percentage as '34%' but I would like to display fractions as well like this: '33.7%'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can simply add `self.pbar.setFormat('%.02f%%' % (self.step))` with your code

and if you want to implemnt more precise formating you can re implement QProgressbar like this maybe

```
class qProress(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    """docstring for qProress"""
    def __init__(self,args):
        super(qProress, self).__init__(args)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.onValueChanged)

    def onValueChanged(self, value):
        self.setFormat('%.02f%%' % (self.prefixFloat))

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.prefixFloat = value
        QtGui.QProgressBar.setValue(self, int(value))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. But I don’t really get what the ’self.step’ is (the code gives an error). Would you mind explaining that to me?

Comment: I tried to use the pbar.value() as argument but then the number does not change anymore during progress (it always shows 0.0%).

Comment: self.step can be any value not pbar.value() say for eg:`for i in range(0,100):   self.pbar.setFormat('%.02f%%' % (i))` hope this helps

Comment: My bad, i guess i should have gotten that. It works now as intended, thanks a lot!